# Ruby equivalent to Python list comprehension

Tags: ruby, loops, list-comprehension

How do I write a loop like this in Ruby?

```
hashTable = [node(None, -1, None, None, -1) for i in range(0, tableLength)]
```

I already tried the following:

```
hash_table = [table_length.times do |x|
  x = NODE.new(@key, @val, @next, @prev, @pos)
  x
end]
```

Where I'm passing the values for `@key, @val...` when I'm calling the class, as follows:

```
this = NODE.new(nil, -1, nil, nil, -1)
this.read_file("alice.txt")
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 6):

You're not far off. Of course, there are a few ways to do this.

The naïve way:

```
hash_table = []

table_length.times do
  hash_table << Node.new(nil, -1, nil, nil, -1)
end
```

The functional way:

```
hash_table = table_length.times.map do
  Node.new(nil, -1, nil, nil, -1)
end
```

The idiomatic way:

```
hash_table = Array.new(table_length) { Node.new(nil, -1, nil, nil, -1) }
```

The last option is the best. The [Array constructor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html), given a Fixnum `n` and block as arguments, will evaluate the block `n` times and return the results as an array. A demonstration I'm fond of is with `rand`:

```
Array.new(5) { rand(0..10) }
# => [3, 10, 0, 8, 7]
```